# Sybase: Replacement for TimeSeries()

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere, sybaseiq

Is there any build in replacement which is doing similar to TimeSeries() of MS SQL on Sybase ASA/IQ?

I'm having a starttime and an endtime as well as an intervall and needs to generate a list of all steps in between.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no equivalent function in SQL Anywhere. Some years ago I used the user defined procedure below in a similar situation but I was only interested in dates. It populated a temporary table which could then be joined to. You could use a similar technique for time intervals, or maybe base something on the sa_rowgenerator() system procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "pears"."DateRange"
(in @StartDate date,in @EndDate date)
result(RowNumber integer,TheDate date)
begin
  --This proceedure can be joined to directly to provide a date range in a query dates are inclusive
  declare @LoopCounter integer;
  declare local temporary table DateRangeTempTable(TheDate date null) on commit delete rows;
  set @LoopCounter=1;
  while @StartDate <= @EndDate loop
    insert into DateRangeTempTable(TheDate) values(@StartDate) ;
    set @StartDate=@StartDate+1
  end loop;
  select Number(*),TheDate from DateRangeTempTable order by TheDate asc
end
```